# Constants or class variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby, constants, class-variables

I've been programming in Ruby for a few months now, and I'm wondering when it is appropriate to use constants over class variables and vice versa. (I'm working in Rails, thinking about constants in models).

```
class Category
  TYPES = %w(listing event business).freeze
end
```

OR

```
class Category
  @@types = %w(listing event business).freeze
  cattr_reader :types
end
```

Are there circumstances where one is preferable to another? Or is it just a matter of taste/style?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The main thing is that by using the CONSTANT notation, you're making it clear to the reader.  the lower case, frozen string gives the impression is *might* be settable, forcing someone to go back and read the RDoc.

Comment: +1 - and think of the poor variable that doesn't get to fulfil its desiny (it never varies)! Related to the RDoc comment, note that constants get documented by default

Comment: Poor little unloved variable.

Answer (score 12):

If these are really constant values that you define in source code and do not want to change during code execution then I would recommend to use constant.

If you plan to set and/or change these values dynamically during execution then use class variable with getters and setters.

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you could put it like this: If you want something that's constant, use a constant. If you want something that's variable, use a variable. It seems like your list of types are constants, seeing it is a frozen array, so I would say it makes sense to use a constant in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Note that class variables are private to a class and its instances (cf. http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_classes.html). However, if you want to make your constant private you can always do:

```
FOO = 18
private_constant :FOO
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the value to ever change during the runtime of your program, *and* you are comfortable with allowing the value to be accessed outside of your class, use a constant.

Otherwise, you can use a class variable. However, be aware that class variables are shared among subclasses and instances of subclasses. So if you might at some point in the future implement a child class, you have to be very careful about your use of class variables.

Refer to the answers here for more on this: [Class variables in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594444/class-variables-in-ruby)