# Ruby class instance variables in subclasses

Tags: ruby, oop, syntax, class-variables

Relying on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10614333/261647), I wrote the following class. When using it, I get an error:

> in 'serialize': undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).

How can I access the variable `@serializable_attrs` in a base class?

**Base class:**

```
# Provides an attribute serialization interface to subclasses.
class Serializable
    @serializable_attrs = {}

    def self.serialize(name, target=nil)
        attr_accessor(name)
        @serializable_attrs[name] = target
    end

    def initialize(opts)
        opts.each do |attr, val|
            instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", val)
        end
    end

    def to_hash
        result = {}
        self.class.serializable_attrs.each do |attr, target|
            if target != nil then
                result[target] = instance_variable_get("@#{attr}")
            end
        end
        return result
    end
end
```

**Usage example:**

```
class AuthRequest < Serializable
    serialize :company_id,      'companyId'
    serialize :private_key,     'privateKey'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class instance variables are not inherited, so the line

```
@serializable_attrs = {}
```

Only sets this in `Serializable` not its subclasses. While you could use the inherited hook to set this on subclassing or change the `serialize` method to initialize `@serializable_attrs` I would probably add

```
def self.serializable_attrs
  @serializable_attrs ||= {}
end
```

And then use that rather than referring directly to the instance variable.

Comment: It's nice that your suggested method initializes AND returns the value.

Comment: Another good thing I found: ActiveSupport's `class_attribute` function (in `active_support/core_ext/class/attribute`).

Comment: If you are using rails then that is a good solution (be careful not to unintentionally update the attribute in place though)

Comment: I'm using it without Rails.