# Why does my concern's cattr_accessor get set to the same value across all subclasses?

Tags: ruby

Here is a runnable test to see the situation

```
require 'active_support'
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    cattr_accessor :value
  end
end

class A
  include MyModule
  self.value = 'a'
end

class B < A
  self.value = 'b'
end

class C < A
  self.value = 'c'
end

puts A.value
puts B.value
puts C.value
```

the output is:

```
$ ruby test.rb
c
c
c
```

Now, I'd think the output should be

```
a
b
c
```

but it's all just whatever was set last.

If I move the include to class B and C and have class A not include the module, then I get the desired output... but then I have includes everywhere... so I feel like this is an issue with my cattr_accessor usage?

Why is this, and how do I achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: No, you created a shared class variable and the output you are getting due to that fact. Look the examples http://apidock.com/rails/Module/mattr_accessor

Comment: See Chuck's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594444/class-variables-in-ruby

Comment: here is how I fixed this:https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/skinny_controllers/commit/791889ec54df36f02635b7c3725f5a6c808bb166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from reddit user [ctcherry](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/4751h6/why_does_my_concerns_cattr_accessor_get_set_to/d0abp5h):

Instead of cattr_accessor try this:

```
class << self
  attr_accessor :foo
end
```

Good information about what is going on here: http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor