# Ruby class level String management, variable vs method

Tags: ruby, string, class

I am seeing a lot of different preferences around the following:

```
class Foo
  VAR = "Some string".freeze

  # or 

  def self.var
    "Some String"
  end
end
```

both can be accessed the same way:

```
Foo::VAR 
#=> "Some String"

Foo::var
#=> "Some String"
```

but you can also do `Foo.var` to get the same string if it was a method. defining it as a variable feels like you break the power of encapsulation that OO gives us. I see however a lot of strings/magic numbers being stored in variables inside class's, this seems like a more common practice.

I am not sure which is right.

**EDIT**
Sorry, my question is a little confusing. I wanted to find out if it's better to store strings in methods vs storing them in variables for a class. Me explaining how to call the methods confused the question.

Comment: `VAR` is a constant. `var` is a class method. Class methods might be called with any syntax (a double colon _and_ a dot.) Everything is right. I vote to close this question.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use `Foo.var` instead of `Foo::var`. As noted in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver): _"You may also use `::` to designate a receiver, but this is rarely used due to the potential for confusion with `::` for namespaces."_

Comment: Sorry so the question is not which is better `Foo::VAR` / `Foo::var` but rather storing the strings in variables vs methods.

Comment: The answer to that would be: store it anywhere you find more funny.

Comment: The main reason for the question I am getting told that storing it in a var is fundamentally bad: "Keep constants for classes and modules, please. Why do we have to scroll to see what this value is from the method? Ruby constants does not work like java or c# where it replaces the text in compile time, it actually adds it to the class instance (if i remember correctly). There is no performance or reusability win here, only more scrolling and the temptation to use this somewhere else instead of writing more OO code."

I just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: @TheLegend This is a heavily opinion-based question, so I cannot really answer it objectively. There are arguments for writing code in different ways, in different scenarios. For example, maybe a string is sometimes a "constant" and other times a computed value; and you'd like to provide a consistent interface for many classes? Neither option is, in my opinion, **"fundamentally bad"** as you say. To see another side of the argument, I recommend the following screencast: http://www.virtuouscode.com/2012/10/01/barewords/

Comment: Show an example of storing a value in a variable.

Comment: _"defining it as a variable [...]"_ – you don't define it as a variable. `@@var` would be a variable, `VAR` is a constant.

Comment: @Stefan sure, constant being a kind of variable. `@var` is an instance variable `@@var` a class variable. it's just a placeholder for something.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, storing `immutable string` in a `CONSTANT` makes more sense. Storing in a `CONSTANT` serves the basic purpose i.e. a constant which is available for all in your `lexical scope(s)`.

Personally, storing `"Some String"` in a method is waste of resource as every-time `self.var` is called then we are initialising the receivers' again which in this scenario is not ideal. I say this as in Ruby `Scope Gate` plays a huge role and due to its dynamic nature and every-time you access a `class` and its `methods` you are entering a new scope. There is a similar question being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903835/class-method-vs-constant-in-ruby-rails) too.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

First, using a constant would guarantee that subclasses use not only the same string but also the same object.

```
  class Bar < Foo; end
  Foo::VAR.object_id == Bar::VAR.object_id # => true
```

And second, calling a class method with `::` syntax is quite confusing, convention is to use `.` (see https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#double-colons)

So i would promote constant use

Comment: `class Foo; def self.var; "str".frozen; end; end; class Bar < Foo; end` also guarantees both use the same object. I don’t see any reasoning in your answer. Conventions are just conventions, you like that, I like this, it’s too opinion based (and biased,) that should never be promoted as an answer.

Comment: indeed using a frozen value returned by a class method, object id is the same for subclasses. (the question should be modified then). btw you have a typo i think you meant `"str".freeze`